# How to provide api token based authentication to Logstash http input

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration, elasticsearch-x-pack

I'm have this simple logstash config, and I would like to add api-token auth to http input. I know how to do that for output to elastic search, but can't figure out is that possible to provide similar to http input

```
input {
    http {
        host => "0.0.0.0"
        port => 8080 # default: 8080
        ssl => false
    }
}

output {
    stdout {
        
    }
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
        api_key => "my_api_key"
        index => "my-local-index"
    }
}
```

Ideal request would be like

```
curl -d '{"message": "my log"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Authorization: ApiKey my_api_key' http://localhost:8080
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The http input creates an http server socket. That can support basic authorization using the user and password options for the input. It does not support using an elasticsearch API key.

Comment: Yes that is what documentation says. But maybe there is a way to authenticate to logstash via API key/token?

Comment: There is not, check the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-http.html#_security), the plugin support basic authentication only.

Comment: That's sad. Thank you for the second point of view